# My update action changes state after dispatching but returns back the initial data not the updated data when getting all contacts

Tags: reactjs, redux, crud, mern

My update action is dispatching but returns back to default in the redux dev tool i can see the change in state for the update action but when getting all contacts i see the initial state back. pls i'd really need your help cause i honestly don't know what is causing.  it

My action code

```
import { employeeConstants } from "./index";
import axiosInstance from "../api";

export const addEmployee = (employeeData) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.post("/employee", employeeData);
      dispatch({ type: employeeConstants.ADD_CONTACT, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  };
};

export const fetchEmployees = async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.get("/employees");
    dispatch({ type: employeeConstants.GET_CONTACTS, payload: data });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

export const deleteEmployee = (_id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.delete(`/employee/${_id}`);
      dispatch({ type: employeeConstants.DELETE_CONTACT, payload: _id });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};

export const editEmployee = (employee) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.put(`/employee/edit/:id`);
      dispatch({ type: employeeConstants.UPDATE_CONTACT, payload: employee });
      console.log(employee);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};

export const getEmployee = (employee) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axiosInstance
      .get("/employee/:id")
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: employeeConstants.GET_CONTACT,
          payload: employee,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

This is what My reducer code looks like

```
import { employeeConstants } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  employees: [],
  employee: {},
};

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case employeeConstants.GET_CONTACTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: action.payload,
      };

    case employeeConstants.ADD_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: action.payload,
      };

    case employeeConstants.DELETE_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: state.employees.filter((employee) => {
          return employee._id !== action.payload;
        }),
      };

    case employeeConstants.UPDATE_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: state.employees.map((employee) =>
          employee._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : employee
        ),
        employee: action.payload,
      };

    case employeeConstants.GET_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default usersReducer;
```

The Home component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteEmployee, fetchEmployees } from "../actions/employee.actions";

const Home = () => {
  const employees = useSelector(state => state.users.employees);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const showAllEnployees = fetchEmployees;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(showAllEnployees);
  }, [showAllEnployees, dispatch]);



  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(deleteEmployee(id));
    toast.success("employee deleted successfully!!");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row d-flex flex-column">
        <Link to="/add" className="btn btn-outline-dark my-5 ml-auto ">
          Add employee
        </Link>
        <div className="col-md-10 mx-auto my-4">
          <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead className="table-header bg-dark text-white">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {employees ? (
                employees.map((employee, _id) => (
                  <tr key={employee._id}>
                    <td>{_id + 1}</td>
                    <td>{employee.name}</td>
                    <td>{employee.email}</td>
                    <td>{employee.phone}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Link
                        to={`/edit/${employee._id}`}
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1"
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Link>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => deleteHandler(employee._id)}
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <th>No employees found</th>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

My Edit Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { editEmployee, getEmployee } from "../actions/employee.actions";

const EditContact = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const history = useNavigate();
  const { employees } = useSelector((state) => state.users);

  const currentContact = employees.find((employee) => employee._id === id);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");

  useEffect((_id) => {
      getEmployee(id);
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentContact) {
      setName(currentContact.name);
      setEmail(currentContact.email);
      setPhone(currentContact.phone);
    }
  }, [currentContact]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const checkEmail = employees.find(
      (employee) => employee._id !== id && employee.email === email && employee
    );

    const checkPhone = employees.find(
      (employee) => employee._id !== id && employee.phone === phone && employee
    );

    if (!email || !name || !phone) {
      return toast.warning("Please fill in all fields!!");
    }

    if (checkEmail) {
      return toast.error("This email already exists!!");
    }
    if (checkPhone) {
      return toast.error("This phone number already exists!!");
    }

   const employee = {
    _id:id,
    name,
    email,
    phone
   } 
  

    dispatch(editEmployee(employee));
    toast.success("Contact updated successfully!!");
    history("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {currentContact ? (
      <div className="row d-flex flex-column">
        <button
          className="btn btn-dark ml-auto my-5"
          onClick={() => history("/")}
        >
          Go back
        </button>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>EDIT STUDENT {id} </h3>
        <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto shadow p-5">
          <form key={id} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Phone"
                value={phone}
                onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between my-2">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => handleSubmit}
              >
                Update Contact
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={() => history("/")}
              >
                cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) : (
        <h1 className="text-center">No Contact {id} Found</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditContact;
```

My backend route code

```
const express = require("express");
const asynchHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const router = express.Router();
const Employee = require("../models/employee");


router.post("/employee", async (req, res) => {
  const employee = new Employee({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
  });
  try {
    const savedEmployee = await employee.save();
    res.json(savedEmployee);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: error });
  }
});

router.get("/employees",  async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getEmployees = await Employee.find();
    if(getEmployees) {
        res.json(getEmployees);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }

});

router.delete("/employee/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deleteEmployee = await Employee.findByIdAndRemove({
      _id: req.params.id,
    });
    res.json(deleteEmployee);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

router.get("/employee/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employee = await Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id);
    res.json(employee);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});


router.put("/employee/edit/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updateEmployee = await Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          phone: req.body.phone,
        },
      },
      { new: true, runValidators:true }
    );
    // updateEmployee.save();
    res.json(updateEmployee);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

//single user
router.get("/employee/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getEmployee = await Employee.findById({ _id: req.params.id });
    if(getEmployee) {
        res.json(getEmployee);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was dispatching but you have not added default case in reducer i.e., to get the state.

```
const initialState = {
  employees: [],
  employee: {} 
};

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_CONTACTS":{
      return {
    ...state,
    employees: action.payload,
      };
     }
    default:
      return state
}
```

And make sure that data variable of get request contains list of employees and you are using same action type name in reducer and dispatch.

Comment: the default case was actually there. the main issue now is when i dispatch my update action, it dispatches in the redux dev tool cause i can see the difference in state but the change does not happen when trying to show all contacts after update action

Comment: Show me how you are fetching state from redux

Comment: i just updated the question and included the action and reducer codes

Comment: I am saying attach the code of component where you are getting employees from redux

Comment: i just added it now

Comment: You are updating contact in redux state only are you updating it on DB too via API? Because it might be possible that you are fetching again the employees data then you see no difference if there will  be no change in DB as well

Comment: yes, i'm trying to update it on the DB too. but it isn't working. pls how do i go about it

Comment: Make a update route at backend and pass the data you want to update

Comment: i've done that, it works when i test it on postman...is there any way i can share my code file with you

Comment: You can paste the component code where you have written update code of API on some button click and inputs

Comment: i've added my edituser component

Answer (score 0):

try to use same action type in the reducer also

```
const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case employeeConstants.GET_CONTACTS: //like this so there is no chance of error
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: action.payload,
      };
```